# How to Write a File to the Root Directory of a Zip File in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip

I'm trying to replace a file in a zipped archive with a script using `zipfile`.  The file is one directory, the archive is in another.  To do this, I copy everything from the original archive into another, excluding the file I want to replace.  Then I write the new version of the file to replace into the new archive, close it, and delete the old archive and rename the new one.  Should be easy, right? ***Wrong.***

For whatever reason, the `zipfile.write()` method has this silly thing it does where it assumes that the second (optional) argument, `arcname` is the same as your file name, unless you specify it.  So, if I have the following:

```
fileName = "C:\\Documents\\file"
archive.write(fileName)
```

I will get an archive with a subarchive called "Documents", and within that will be the file.  I want the file to be in the root directory of the archive (sidenote: is 'root directory' the right term for what I'm refering to?)

Thing's I've Tried:

- `archive.write(fileName,'')`  This produced a weird file in the archive, which could not be opened.
- `archive.write(fileName, archive)` I really thought this would work, but the system ***really*** didn't like it.
- `archive.write(fileNameWithoutPath)` This one returned an error, since Python could no longer find the file.

So how do I specify that I want to put the file in the root directory of the archive and still specify its path so Python can find it?

Minor, and semi-related question: Is there a way to create the new archive such that it is hidden in windows explorer?

Comment: Hi! You might want to tag this with `python` as well. You may get a better response!

Comment: Did you try using os.path.basename to trim the filename and pass it as arcname?

Comment: From your description of the write method with the second argument being the name in the archibe what does archive.write(filename, fileNameWithoutPath) do

Comment: I have no idea why it works, but your suggestion does @Mark!  I would have thought this would give me a folder with the same name as the file.  Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you want a entry in the zipfile called file containin the contents of `C:\Documents\file`

From [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects)

> ZipFile.write(filename[, arcname[, compress_type]])
>        Write the file named filename to the archive, giving it the archive name arcname

so you want

```
archive.write(fileName, fileNameWithoutPath)
```

The first argument is the file that goes in the zip and the second is the name that is to be used in the archive, as it contains no path separators it will not create any directories.

Comment: +1 I saw that with intellisense but incorrectly assumed arcname refers to the zip file you're creating. Should have read the description!